# change_column migration issues with Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using PostGres and Rails 6 for a project with Docker. I have the following migration file which i am using to turn column types from string or numeric to integer:

```
class ChangeColumnTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    change_column :drivers, :yearOfBirth, :integer, using: 'yearOfBirth::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :racingNumber, :integer, using: 'racingNumber::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :noRaces, :integer, using: 'noRaces::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :noPoles, :integer, using: 'noPoles::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :noPodiums, :integer, using: 'noPodiums::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :noWins, :integer, using: 'noWins::integer'
    change_column :drivers, :user_id, :integer, using: 'user_id::integer'
  end
end
```

When I run the migration I get errors like

```
Caused by:
myapp_1     | PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column drivers.yearofbirth does not exist
myapp_1     | LINE 1: ...rivers" ALTER COLUMN "drivers" TYPE integer USING drivers.ye...

HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "drivers.yearOfBirth".
```

My column is camel cased which might be the issue as the yearOfBirth name is correct. Is there any way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```rb
change_column :drivers, :yearOfBirth, 'integer USING CAST(yearOfBirth AS integer)'
```

If that doesn't work (I'd back it all up before trying it, just to be safe):

1. Create a new int column with another name
2. Move the converted data there
3. Drop the original column
4. Change the new column name to the original one

```rb
create_column :drivers, :yearOfBirthInt, :integer

Driver.update_all('yearOfBirthInt = CAST(yearOfBirth AS integer)')

# If the above doesn't work, try this, but it's a lot slower:
# Driver.transaction do
#   Driver.each { |d| d.update!(yearOfBirthInt: d.yearOfBirth.to_i) }
# end

remove_column :drivers, :yearOfBirth
rename_column :drivers, :yearOfBirthInt, :yearOfBirth
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks. That was a typo when i put the code on Stack Overflow. The error is the same though.